Hibernate seems to ignore the dialect I specify
I'm using Olingo JPA for producing an OData API.
The database I'm connecting to doesn't support the 'LOCATE' function; instead it implements 'POSITION'.
This seems to be true of a few databases: postgres, sqlserver and snowflake.
I have set the dialect using properties, for example:
spring.data.jdbc.dialect=postgresql
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

I can see that org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect calls
functionFactory.locate_positionSubstring();
I can also see that the SqlServerDialect calls
functionFactory.locate_charindex();
My understanding of these is that for PostgreSQLDialect it should use the position function, and for SqlServerDialect, it should use the charindex function instead of locate.
However, when I turn on logging (spring.jpa.show-sql=true), I am seeing logs like:
SELECT COUNT(E0.id) S0 FROM MY_TABLE E0 WHERE (LOCATE(?, E0.value) <> ?)
This is because the Olingo library v2 uses a criteriabuilder and calls locate on it here.
Is my expectation that these dialects (or if I implement my own) should cause hibernate to not call the database with a LOCATE function, but instead use charindex or position? Why is it still sending LOCATE queries (Which then fail)?

This might be happening because Olingo uses its own entity manager, which may not be reading the values from the spring initialized one. You can try setting them like this
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean springEMF = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        springEMF.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        springEMF.setDataSource(dataSource);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        props.setProperty("spring.jpa.database-platform", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        springEMF.setJpaProperties(props);
        springEMF.afterPropertiesSet();
        

I have some code for reference for Eclipse Link Provider, that you can take reference from here
